# How to resolve "Circular dependency" in Microsoft Project

Tags: planning, ms-project

I am working in Microsoft Project for creating Low level plan in `.mpp` files.

I am having the circular dependency error as shown in below snapshot:

[image]

I want to know, is there any out-of-box functionality/tool/macro to find the circular dependency in Project(.mpp) files. I am debugging manually right now & plan has many thousand lines.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found a easily approach.

- Insert a new column in MSP copy all predeccessor column value in the new custom text field(say Text1_Pred)
- now bulk delete all values in predeccessor column
- Now copy back all the value from Text1_Pred into Predeccessor Column
  again
- it would start giving error with "Task ID No" as pasting error for
  circular reference. Note TaskId.
- It give you option to ignore problem or continue without problem or cancel
- Choose NO ("continue without problem ") option to remove.

Hope it will help someone else with the problem.

Source:

http://www.domorethanmanage.com/articles/2008/05/29/Resolvingcircularreferenc.html

http://pranavwithyou.wordpress.com/2014/06/02/how-to-resolve-circular-dependency-in-microsoft-project/

https://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/resolve-circular-reference-sub-project-160953.aspx